# Is there anyway to evaluate the estimation results of least square

Tags: machine-learning, regression, statistics, optimization, parameter-estimation

Consider the scenario where a practical problem is tackled utilizing the method of least squares. Upon each iteration, an estimation of the parameter $\theta$ is derived via $\hat{\theta} = (X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ denote arrays of $x_i$ and $y_i$ for $i$ ranging from 1 to $n$. However, it is pertinent to acknowledge the result may differ in each estimation. Let's say N values of $\hat{\theta}$ are derived from N estimations, each of which is an outcome obtained using arrays of $x$ and $y$.
Is there a methodology to assess the confidence associated with $\hat{\theta}$ procured from each least squares estimation?

Comment: Confidence intervals for the coefficients?

Comment: @Dave could you please be more specific?

Comment: I'd encourage you to read about regression confidence intervals. Perhaps [these](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~yxie77/isye2028/lecture12.pdf) lecture slides from a Georgia Tech course could be a starting point.

Comment: @Dave Sorry for the late reply. Great attitude to your kind help, and I'll try to look into it first.